# Solve the Integral Equation Involving Laplace Transforms

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I want to solve $\int^\infty_0x'(T)x(t-T)dT=6t^3$ where $x(0)=0$

I did the Laplace transform to both sides, and the left side is a convolution, so I then have

$X(s)x(s)=\frac{36}{s^4}$, but here I'm stuck.  Any help to move forward?  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have $X(s)$ and $x(s)$? It should be $sX(s)^2$ see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS of the equation is, after LT, $s X(s)^2$.  Thus,

$$X(s) = 6 s^{-5/2}$$

According to [this](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/LapInv3.pdf) table, the ILT is

$$x(t) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}} t^{3/2} $$

If I have time later, I will derive this result via contour integration in the complex plane.